# How to bridge from any Type to Generic without switching through all possible Objects conforming to Protocol in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, generics, swiftui, protocols

**Context**

I have a generic SwiftUI view called `ComponentRow` and would like to use it in different places inside my app. However, my model only returns the `Component` as `(any Component)?`, which is why I used a `Switch` to bridge between `any` and the generic `ComponentRow` view *(see variant A in code example)*.

I came with an idea to simplify the code *(see variant B in code example)*, however, I get the following Compiler Error:

> Adjacent operators are in non-associative precedence group 'ComparisonPrecedence'

---

**Code**

```swift
protocol Component {
    static var name: String { get }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        // Variant A: Current Solution
        switch component {
        case let componentA as ComponentA: ComponentRow<ComponentA>()
        case let componentB as ComponentB: ComponentRow<ComponentB>()
        case let componentC as ComponentC: ComponentRow<ComponentC>()
        default: EmptyView()
        }

        // Variant B: My Idea, does not work
        if let safeComponent = component {
            EventRow<type(of: safeComponent)>(for: profile, with: event)
        }
    }

    var component: (any Component)? {
        // Some Logic...
    }
}

struct ComponentRow<C: Component>: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text(C.name)
    }
}
```

---

**Question**

- Is there a way to avoid switching through all possible objects conforming to `Component` to initiate the appropriate `ComponentRow`?

Comment: Give ComponentRow an initializer?

Comment: @matt thanks for your answer, however, how would that solve the problem of needing to switch through all possible objects conforming to `Component`?

Comment: Well, that's hard to answer, because the code shown in the question is so very far from making any sense.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use generics properly you need an ***instance*** of an object that conforms to the protocol `Component`.

Here's a quick example of what I think you're trying to accomplish:

```swift
protocol Component {
    var name: String { get set } // <~ Not static
}

struct FirstComponent: Component {
    var name: String
}

struct SecondComponent: Component {
    var name: String
}

struct ComponentRow<C: Component>: View {
    let component: C
    var body: some View {
        Text(component.name)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let first = FirstComponent(name: "Foo") // <~ instance
    let second = SecondComponent(name: "Bar") // <~ instance
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ComponentRow(component: first)
            ComponentRow(component: second)
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

May be something like :

```swift
protocol Component {
    var name: String { get }
}

struct ComponentA: Component {
    var name: String = "A"
}
struct ComponentB: Component {
    var name: String {
        get {
            return "B"
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        // Variant B: My Idea, does not work
        if let safeComponent = components {
            ComponentRow(component: safeComponent)
        } else {
            EmptyView()
        }
    }
    
    var components: (any Component)? {
        // Some Logic...
        return (ComponentB())
    }
}

struct ComponentRow: View {
    // You do not need to declare a generic type
    var component: any Component
    var body: some View {
        Text(component.name)
    }
}
```